# Convert C# code to vb.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

What is the equivalent code in `vb.net` for this `c#` code ?

```
 DataFilter1.OnFilterAdded += new DataFilter.RefreshDataGridView(DataFilter1_OnFilterAdded);
```

I have used a conversion tool, and  got this code :

```
DataFilter1.OnFilterAdded += New DataFilter.RefreshDataGridView(AddressOf DataFilter1_OnFilterAdded)
```

But it seems that is not correct ..

Comment: Side note: The C# code can be shortened to `DataFilter1.OnFilterAdded += DataFilter1_OnFilterAdded;`

Answer (score 3):

```
AddHandler DataFilter1.OnFilterAdded, AddressOf DataFilter1_OnFilterAdded
```

Comment: Exception Description : E:\sites\EPER EN\Admin\DB\Default.aspx.vb(12): error BC30002: Type 'DataFilter.RefreshDataGridView' is not defined.  Source File :   Line : 0   ..  ?

Comment: I believe you need the `AddressOf` operator here... and after you've added that, this answer would just become a duplicate of the other two answers, but without any explanation.

Comment: forgot to type that part indeed but i think it wa sclear what i meant ;) No autocorrect on SO :p

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [`AddHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka.aspx) which is used to subscribe to events (when you're not using a [`Handles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6k46st1y.aspx) clause):

```
AddHandler DataFilter1.OnFilterAdded, AddressOf DataFilter1_OnFilterAdded
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to register an event handler programmatically, you have to use: [`AddHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
AddHandler DataFilter1.OnFilterAdded, AddressOf DataFilter1_OnFilterAdded
```

[**How to: Create Event Handlers in ASP.NET Web Pages**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6w2tb12s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)